# Jasper insert page number when pagination is ignored

Tags: java, pagination, jasper-reports

I would like to insert page numbers in an Excel report (only when it is printed) generated with `Jasper 3.7.5`. 
The problem is that I have `isIgnorePagination` set to true, therefore I can not use the `pageFooter` tag in the `jrxml` template.
The `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.footer.right` property AFAIK cannot interpret expressions, therefore I can **not** insert the `PAGE_NUMBER` variable like this:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.footer.right" value="$V{PAGE_NUMBER}"/>
```

So how can I insert page numbers in this case? I only need the page numbers to be displayed when the report is printed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use the Excel page counter:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.footer.right" 
        value="Page &amp;P of &amp;N"/>
```

`&P` is the number of the current page, `&N` the total number of pages.

Additional variables are:

- `&A`: Name of the sheet
- `&D`: Current date
- `&T`: Current time
- `&F`: File name
- `&Z`: Full file name

Comment: I wish this would solve the problem but I still get "Page &P" in the Excel print preview. Is there anything else I need to set?

Comment: Moreover, if I hardcode it in the jrxml template I get SAXParseException that the entity "P" was referenced but not declared.  But that is on Jasper side. If this is Excel page counter than do I have to set it, o declare it somehow? I work with Excel 2007.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to escape the `&`. These are special markup symbols which tell Excel to replace them with the appropriate values. They havn't changed between Excel versions for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to parse the XLS with the Apache POI API and modify it accordingly before it is sent back to the browser. I don not know whether this is possible. If it is possible then still it is a kind of hack instead of a good solution.

Comment: It is possible: `workbook.getSheetAt().getFooter().setRight("...");`. See my answer.